# Reading rows in cassandra and de-serialzation issue

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'd like to get all rows from a column family and display all columns as well. I tried this one:

```
// Static import of HFactory!

// First, insert the data
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(fKeyspace, fStringS);
mutator.insert("fahrer1", "Fahrer", createStringColumn("first", "John"));
mutator.insert("fahrer2", "Fahrer", createStringColumn("first", "Vorname"));
mutator.insert("fahrer2", "Fahrer", createStringColumn("second", "Nachname"));
mutator.
    addInsertion("fahrer3", "Fahrer",
            createColumn("first", "Firstname", fStringS,
                    fStringS)).
    addInsertion("fahrer3", "Fahrer",
            createColumn("second", "Lastname", fStringS,
                    fStringS)).
    addInsertion("fahrer3", "Fahrer",
            createColumn("age", 29L, fStringS, fLongS))
    .execute();

// Now select..
CqlQuery<String, String, String> cqlQuery =
   new CqlQuery<String, String, String>(fKeyspace,fStringS,fStringS,fStringS);
cqlQuery.setQuery("SELECT * FROM ColumnFamily");

QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, String>> result = cqlQuery.execute();

CqlRows<String, String, String> rows = result.get();
for (Row<String, String, String> row : rows.getList()) {
    System.out.println(row.getKey() + ":");
    for(HColumn<String, Object>col : row.getColumnSlice().getColumns()) {
        System.out.println(col.getName() + " : " + col.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that all the columns which have long-values for example are empty. If I change the last "parameterizer" to Object, I get a "CorruptedStreamException". How do I have to do this?

UPDATE: this is the output using CLI

```
[default@Autorennen] list Fahrer;
Using default limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: fahrer1
=> (column=first, value=John, timestamp=1308392358211000)
-------------------
RowKey: fahrer2
=> (column=first, value=SecondUpdated, timestamp=1308392358350000)
=> (column=second, value=584e6163686e616d65, timestamp=1308392358284000)
-------------------
RowKey: fahrer3
=> (column=age, value=000000000000001d, timestamp=1308392358286002)
=> (column=first, value=Firstname, timestamp=1308392358286000)
=> (column=second, value=4c6173746e616d65, timestamp=1308392358286001)
```

Comment: What happens if you query the same ColumnFamily through the Cassandra CLI? Have you confirmed that the expected data is present in your column family?

Comment: Hi DNA I updated my question to answer your questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using byte[] instead of Object? The underlying type of all Cassandra data items is a byte array. e.g.

```
QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, byte[]>>
```

This is based on guesswork from web examples, as I use a Python client rather than Java...

You could also try omitting the generics:

```
CqlResult result = executeQuery("select * from ColumnFamily");
for (CqlRow row : result.getRows()) {
    System.out.println(new String (row.getKey()));
}
```

and see what types you get back, if any.

Comment: I'll try this, sounds good (it fits to the answer I get in the user group a few hours ago :-)). I'll post the correct code here as update of my question!

Comment: Omitting the generics does not work :-/ The byte[]-array stuff looks good, finishing some tests...

Answer (score 4):

The answer from the ML: 
http://groups.google.com/group/hector-users/browse_thread/thread/8246ad59c9d5cf9d

Also, please take a look at the new template package. It provides significantly more sane retrieval of typed results. Here is a getting started guide utilizing such:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Getting-started-%285-minutes%29

Comment: Indeed, that's the ML answer :-) Thank you for the hint with the templates! I didn't use it because of the "Thrift" in the method names... Hector is a wrapper  around Thrift so I thought that this call would be "dirty"... I'll try them and write again :-)